# how to add multiple values to duplicate enum type

Tags: java, enums

I have two enum classes College.java and Student.java

here is the code snippet for both the classes.

```
public enum College {

   ID("Id of College"), NAME("Name of College"), ADDRESS("Address of College");

   private final String description;

   private College(String details) {
       this.description = description;
   }

}

public enum Student {
    ROLL(College.ID, "Roll No of Student"), CLASS(College.NAME, "Class of Student"),
    PLACE(College.ADDRESS, "Place of Student"), STUDENTID(setMap());

    private final String description;
    private final College college;
    private Map<college, String> attributes;

    private Student(College college, String details) {
        this.college = college;
        this.details = details;
    }
    private Student(Map<college, String> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
        for(college key: attributes.keySet()) {
            this.college=key;
            this.description=attributes.get(key);
        }
        
    }
    
    private Map<college, String> setMap() {
        Map<college, String> map = new HashMap<college, String>();
        map.put(College.ID ,"ID of college");
        map.put(College.NAME,"Name of Student"); 
        map.put(College.ADDRESS,"Address of the College"); 
        return map;
    }
}
```

My question is that i am unable to add STUDENTID enum in Student class where i want to tag multiple College Enums.
Eg:

```
STUDENTID((College.ID ,"ID of college"),(College.NAME,"Name of Student"),(College.ADDRESS,"Address of the College"));
```

It is just an example but i want to tag multiple College class enums to Student class. Is there any way to do that? Please help me here

Comment: What do you mean you can't add tag multiple College enums? Your code compiles if you add the necessary constructor declarations.

Comment: My code is throwing error if I am adding STUDENTID enum to the student class as mentioned in the example above

Comment: I want a enum which has multiple enums tagged from college class.. If I am trying STUDENTID(College.ID , "Roll no"), STUDENTID(College.NAME, "Name"),  then it is not taking duplicate enums. So I want multiple College enums tagged to a single Student Enum

Comment: Exactly what error is it throwing?

Comment: First of all, please always show complete code, including the fields and constructors of your classes. Second, what are the fields that you want to use to describe a single Student instance? A single College plus a single name? Or a mapping from College instances to names? Third, I'd recommend to rename the enums to be less confusing to readers. E.g. the instances of Student surely don't represent students, maybe some metadata on students (ROLL, CLASS, and PLACE surely aren't meant to name some students).

Answer (score 0):

As @Sweeper suggested, you need a proper constructor, try below

```
public enum College {

   ID("Id of College"), NAME("Name of College"), ADDRESS("Address of College");

   private final String details;

   College(String details) {
       this.details = details;
   }

}

public enum Student {
    ROLL(College.ID, "Roll No of Student"), CLASS(College.NAME, "Class of Student"),
    PLACE(College.ADDRESS, "Place of Student");

    private final String details;
    private College college

    Student(College college, String details) {
        this.college = college;
        this.details = details;
    }
}
```